# Page transitions keeping a footer and header for variable page content

Tags: css, angularjs

I am using angular and css for sliding page transitions, and had a nice working version of transitions similar to [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/PqhvmW?p=preview) plnker. This worked ok but the css was using 'absolute' which took the element in question out of the flow of the page, hiding the rest of it - namely the footer.

The content of what is being transitioned in varies page to page. The footer is hidden because the many parents of the content being displayed have height 0px;

So I removed `absolute` and now the transitions happen something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/YZOZfWSNMLQTzpQlVvmF?p=preview), where the divs are again in the flow of the page, but when transition are floated above and below each other.

I can use transitions to make the new div enter at the same level as the exiting div by changing

```
.slideRight.ng-leave {
    transition-property: all;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

.slideRight.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    transition-property: all;
    transform: translate3d(100%,0,0);
}
```

to

```
.slideRight.ng-leave {
    transition-property: all;
    transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.slideRight.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {
    transition-property: all;
    transform: translate3d(100%,-100%,0);
}
```

as shown in this [plnker](http://plnkr.co/edit/0Hj0xVJUcY4mM9j34Yja?p=preview). However, the issue is that the div height is still affecting the page, so you can see a vertical scroll bar as the new div enters and the rest of the page is affected.

The divs which enter the page can be different heights, so I don't think simply setting a defined height on a parent div and setting `overflow-y: hidden` is an option.

Comment: I don't get why is `position:absolute;` not an option? It takes this elements out of the flow, but the `.page-container` is relative, so this element acts like a wrapper which is in the flow.

Comment: @JanHommes I remember trying to get this to work with a footer and struggling. I want the footer to stay on the page similarly to the top nav. Perhaps position:absolute may be ok

Comment: the element is always absolute to the next positioned element. If there is none, than it is absolute to the body. So if your page-transition is relative to your container-div and the footer is relative to the body, there should be no problem.

Comment: @JanHommes - I understand but I seem to be tripping up somewhere. If you can make the first plnker I linked to show a footer, that's an easy 50rep for you...

Comment: You want the footer to be fixed at the bottom like the nav?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/AhDT3C - There is only one down take: I am using vh and if your screen is really small, the scrollbar goes behinde the top menu.

Comment: @BojanPetkovski - not fixed, just appear underneath like a normal floating div. When I try, it just gets hidden under the angular content

Comment: Seems impossible with pure CSS. The absolute positioning even in a relative div is giving the parent a height of 0px. Meaning the footer displays directly under the header - being covered by the angular content ...now I remember why I didnt use absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you go.](http://plnkr.co/edit/hNFF2TToFf2Rux4v96QL?p=preview) i edited the first fiddle you posted. Styling is inline because I couldnt be bothered changign the css but you get the drift.

```
  <nav>
            <a ng-click="go('/page1', 'slideLeft')">Page 1</a>
            <a ng-click="go('/page2', 'slideRight')">Page 2</a>
            <a ng-click="go('/page3', 'slideDown')">Page 3</a>
            <a ng-click="go('/page4')">Page 4</a> <!-- note: no transition specified -->
        </nav>

        <!-- App Content Container -->
        <div class="page-container">
            <div ng-view="" class="page-view" ng-class="pageAnimationClass"></div>
        </div>

        <footer>
          <div style="height: 50px; width:100%; position: fixed; bottom: 0; display: block; background: white; "><br>Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer Footer</div>
        </footer>
```

The example you posted uses a fixed position header with an absolutely positioned full screen content area. The content actually moves right and left underneath the header and the footer i added.

There are other ways to do it but fixed headers and footer generally work well with web apps.

if you wanted a dynamic footer, you would need to restyle your content area. I would center your header and footer items with a margin: 0 auto and make the content full width, with a centered div inside it that is the animated element. It should slide left and right as you intend without breaking your footer.

Keep in mind though that if you transition in items of differing height your footer will jitter as it repositions itself. Maybe consider adding a callback animation on your footer that fades it out and in again whenever the page transition animation plays and stops.

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up using javascript (now converting to angular) to grab the contents height each time and assigning it as the parent divs height. Still for your effort and the footer animation idea I'll give you the bounty when it becomes available.